# CodeIgniter htaccess Issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, controller

I guess this is a general htaccess question instead of something specifically for CodeIgniter, however, I came across it doing work on my own CodeIgniter application.

I have a folder in the root directory called "admin" where the CSS, JS, and Images are. If I type in the following: `http://example.com/admin/` it directs to that folder. I want my `routes.php` file to control all of that and send the user to the admin panel. Here's the route section:

`$route['admin'] = 'admin';` (I have a controller that is called admin, and it's setup correctly)

How do I fix this issue? I'm assuming this is an htaccess file issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it via .htaccess, but that will mean that the requests for the javascript and css will be routed as well: if, for instance, the browser tries to load `http://baseurl.com/admin/style.css`, the system will try to serve the output of the `style.css()` method in the `admin` controller, leading to an error.

How about renaming your resources folder to something more sensitive - for instance, `resources`?

That way you won't have to touch the .htaccess either.